# Building whatsapp group chat clone with notifications feature

Tags: node.js, notifications, groupchat

I'm planning to build a community platform app in react native. The use case would be for any user to join those communities just like an whatsapp group and interact with other members. Now i'm stuck planning for stack and technologies to be used.

1. Should i be concerned about handling traffic load of messages using something like kafka? If yes, where can i get some reference examples of real world use-case which would also store messages in db (Using NodeJs).
2. How do i notify about the pending new message to user who was offline?

Comment: Use Firebase. You need a APNS/GCM service, not a message queue for notifications